# Polygon plot in matlab with function

Tags: matlab, function, plot, polygon

I want to create a function in matlab which plots a polygon based on number of sides of the polygon which should be the input of the function.How can I generate this code?

Comment: You need an equation or a formulation which will be able to describe each type of polygon you want to create. When you have that, you can start translating it into code. When you have a code started, you can ask here again for help if it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Generating Polygons from Sampling a Circle

You can take sample points along a circle and join them, but of course, depending on the criteria for the generated polygons this may or may not suit your requirements. In this case, you'll need the number of points to be 1 greater than the number of edges to close the shape. Here we denote a vector `Theta` which takes evenly spaced sample angles from **0** to **2π** radians (**0°** to **360°**). These sample angles stored in `Theta` are then used to calculate xy-points along a circle by using `sin()` and `cos()` relationships. The last step is to multiply by the `Radius` since `sin()` and `cos()` of an angle are normalized to the unit circle.

[image: Polygon Plot with Specified Number of Edges]

```
Number_Of_Edges = 6;

Radius = 100;
Theta = linspace(0,2*pi,Number_Of_Edges+1);
X_Points = Radius*cos(Theta);
Y_Points = Radius*sin(Theta);

plot(X_Points,Y_Points);
title("Polygon with " + num2str(Number_Of_Edges) + " Edges");
grid;
```

---

### Function Call:

```
Number_Of_Edges = 6;
Polygon_Plot(Number_Of_Edges);
```

### Function Form:

```
function [] = Polygon_Plot(Number_Of_Edges)
Radius = 100;
Theta = linspace(0,2*pi,Number_Of_Edges+1);
X_Points = Radius*cos(Theta);
Y_Points = Radius*sin(Theta);


plot(X_Points,Y_Points);
title("Polygon with " + num2str(Number_Of_Edges) + " Edges");
grid;

end
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**